# VC-dimension of the infinite intersection of two spheres

Tags: machine-learning, vc-dimension

I'm searching for an upper-bound for the VC-dimension of the infinite intersection of two spheres.
Thanks

Comment: How many spheres are interesting—two or infinity? And in what space? Finite-dimensional Euclidean or more exotic?

Comment: To be more precise, VC-dimension of the infinite phases of the moon. Each phase is the intersection of two spheres. In 2D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the OP has clarified that the question is about the VC-dimension of the 2-fold intersection of spheres in $\mathbb{R}^d$ (in fact, $d=2$ was specified), a simple upper bound can be stated. The VC-dim of spheres in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is the same as that of half-spaces (via an easy scaling argument) --- namely, $d+1$.
Lemma 3.2.3 of Blumer et al. (1989) bounds the VC-dim of the $k$-fold union/intersection of a class of VC-dim $d$ by
$$
2kd\log(3k).
$$
Thus, $2\cdot2\cdot2\log(6)\approx 14$ is an upper-bound on the VC-dimension in the OP.

A. Blumer, A. Ehrenfeucht, D. Haussler, and M. K. Warmuth. Learnability and the Vapnik-Chervonenkis dimension. J. Assoc. Comput. Mach., 36(4):929–965, 1989. ISSN 0004-5411.

Comment: Thank you very much!